# @SubclassMapping order

Tags: java, mapstruct

First time using MapStruct (1.5.0.Beta2)

Say I have the following class hierarchy: `C extends B extends A` and `Cdto extends Bdto extends Adto`.  And the following mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", subclassExhaustiveStrategy = RUNTIME_EXCEPTION)
public interface MyMapper{
    @SubclassMapping(source = B.class, target = Bdto.class)
    @SubclassMapping(source = C.class, target = Cdto.class)
    Adto map(A source);
}
```

When I map a list of C objects I actually get a list of Bdtos.  If however I change the ordering to:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", subclassExhaustiveStrategy = RUNTIME_EXCEPTION)
public interface MyMapper{
    @SubclassMapping(source = C.class, target = Cdto.class)
    @SubclassMapping(source = B.class, target = Bdto.class)
    Adto map(A source);
}
```

I get a list of Cdtos as expected.  Is this by design?  Is there any way to make it less dependent on annotation order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. [The reason for this is to let the user control the order for the mappings.](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/2512#discussion_r703783542) The same behavior is used for `@Mapping` annotations.

Your first example should also get a compiler warning, although it might refer to the wrong type (target instead of source) at the moment. This should be fixed in the next release.